# Named pipes: C# server, C++ client

Tags: c#, c++, named-pipes

I wrote 2 pairs of named pipe client/server programs: 
1st pair in C# (.NET 4)
2nd pair in C++ (un-managed)

All 4 test programs use the same pipe name \\.\pipe\mypipe

The C# pair work fine with each other - I send a message from the client and it is received by the server.
The C++ pair work also fine with each other.

But... when I try to run the C# client with the C++ server, or the C++ client with the C# server - then it doesn't work. The client is unable to connect to the server.

Is there something preventing the C++ client from working with the .NET server?
Should it work?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are sending binary data, are you sure the binary format matches between the two implementations?

Comment: The problem is before sending the data. The problem is that the opening the pipe on the client side fails.

Comment: How does it fail?  Do you get an exception, does the app hang?

Comment: This is how the client opens the pipe:

<pre>
hPipe=CreateFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\mypipe", 
     GENERIC_WRITE,//GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
     0,
     NULL,
     OPEN_EXISTING,
     0,
     NULL) ;


if ( hPipe!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
 return 0; //Success!!!
}


err = GetLastError();
if(err!=ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
{
 printf("Could not open pipe, GetLastError=%u\n", err);
 return -1 ;
  }

</pre>
Create file returns an invalid handle. GetLastError() returns 2.

Comment: What is C# pipename value? Is it "mypipe"?

Comment: It is 

\\\\.\\pipe\\mypipe

Comment: C#'s NamedPipeClientStream, NamedPipeServerStream automatically append  "\.\\pipe\"  to the name.

Comment: Thank you Alexm, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NamedPipeClientStream`  and `NamedPipeServerStream` prefix "\\.\pipe\" to the name automatically.

C++ client code:

```
hPipe = CreateFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\mypipe", ...)
```

corresponding C# server code:

```
var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("mypipe", ...)
```

Comment: @yaronkl if this answer solved your problem, then you should mark it as the answer

Comment: Technically the NamedPipeClientStream and NamedPipeServerStream prepend the "\\.\pipe\" to the name.  Append means add after the text.  If they appended, the name "mypipe" would turn into "mypipe\\.\pipe\"